# "@media screen" and menubar

Tags: html, css

I am working on a navigation bar, and I am stuck because my code won't work as attended. When on mobile (760px) I want my nav-bar to show 3 div classes as an icon for the 'pop up' menubar. I just can't figure out why it won't show up.

**The code, CSS:**

```
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: #5d4954;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.logo{
    color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-links{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 30%;
}
.nav-links li{
    list-style: none;
}
.nav-links a{
    color: rgb(226, 226, 226); 
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.burger{
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div{
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    margin: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
    .nav-links{
        width: 60%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:760px){
    body{
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
         right: 0px;
         height: 92vh;
         top: 8vh;
         background-color: #5d4954;
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: column;
         align-items: center;
         width: 30%;
         transform: translateX(100%);
         transition: transform 0.5 ease-in;
    }
    .nav-links li{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .burger{
        display: block;
    }
}

.nav-active{
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

**Code, HTML:**

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="witdh=device-witdh, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    <title>NAVIGATION</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <h4>The Nav</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links"
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            <li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            <li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Work</a>
            <li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Our Project</a>
            <li>
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If anyone, can see the problem, it would be great if you could tell me.

Comment: There's a typo in this line: `transition: tranform 0.5 ease-in;` --> "transform"! So the transition won't happen and the element will stay outside the visible part due to the `ttransform: translateX(100%);` setting.

Comment: Arh, did not see. Did not solve the issue though :/ thx anyway <3

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem with the code. And it a simple mistake, but one I did not think would matter, or can't see why it worked. So if anyone can explain why this solved the issue, that would be great. Anyway, I moved the 'div burger class' to before the 'nav-links' in my HTML code. I am not sure why this fixed the issue, but it did. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="witdh=device-witdh, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" rel='Stylesheet'>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    <title>NAVIGATION</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <h4>The Nav</h4>
        </div>
                <div class="burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Work</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Our Project</a>
            </li>
    </nav>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I can't figure out why it would matter to move the code, but I did in an attempt to see if that was the reason, and it was. If you can explain to me why this is the answer, that would be great.

Answer (score -1):

Use Bootstrap for designs like this first.There is an error at the top of the css code you wrote, fix it.

```
       body, *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

It has to be like this